# how to make the filter which have multiple tabs and get data dynamically in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Here is the update of my question:

I am having a filter tab from the database but and doing a loop to show the filters tab.

PROBLEM

But the problem is when we click on tabs it should show a dropdown from where I can choose what we want to filter. but its only showing first filter and other are not working.

**EDIT**
    my view file

```
<form id="tabForms" action="{{route('o')}}" method="GET">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 filter-bootstrap" style="padding:0px;margin-bottom:20px;">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle"
              data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" 
              style="background:#FFF;color:#575962;border:solid 1px #e7ecf1;box-shadow: none;font-weight: 300;
              font-size: 15px;text-transform: capitalize;padding: 5px 12px;height: 35px;border-radius:3px 0px 0px 3px;">Add Search Field &nbsp;
              </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu productFilter" id="filters">
                    <li id="Payment Status" onclick="productFilter(this.id)" ><a href="#">Payment Status</a></li>
                    <li id="Shipping Status" onclick="productFilter(this.id)" ><a href="#">Shipping Status</a></li>
                    <li id="Order Total" onclick="productFilter(this.id)" ><a href="#">Order Total</a></li>
                    <li id="Item Weight" onclick="productFilter(this.id)" ><a href="#">Item Weight</a></li>
                    <li id="Shipping class Name" onclick="productFilter(this.id)" ><a href="#">Shipping class Name</a></li>
                    <li id="Shipping Country" onclick="productFilter(this.id)" ><a href="#">Shipping Country</a></li>
                    <li id="Refund Status" onclick="productFilter(this.id)" ><a href="#">Refund Status</a></li>
                    <li id="Shipping class Name" onclick="productFilter(this.id)" ><a href="#">Shipping class Name</a></li>
                    <li id="Warehouse Location" onclick="productFilter(this.id)" ><a href="#">Warehouse Location</a></li>
                    <li id="Shipment Status Date" onclick="productFilter(this.id)" ><a href="#">Shipment Status Date</a></li>
                    <li id="Payment status" onclick="productFilter(this.id)" ><a href="#">Payment status</a></li>

                </ul>
                 <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="productFilterType" value="" id="productFilterType"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /btn-group -->
                                         <!--show text on input -->
                                         <div class="filter-top">
                                                 @php
                                                       use App\Filter;
                                                       $userId = Auth::id();
                                                           $filters = Filter::where('user_id',$userId)->get();

                                                        foreach($filters as $getfilter)
                                                         { 
                                                             $filter_name = $getfilter->filter_name;
                                                             $filter_id = $getfilter->id;
                                                             @endphp

                                                              <label id="inputTagFilterId" class=filter-id{{$filter_id}} style="color:#666;margin:7px;"> {{$filter_name}} &nbsp; <span class="close-tab"><a style="border-left: dotted 1px #666;color: #666;">&nbsp;X&nbsp;</a></span></label>


                                                        @php  }



                                                 @endphp


                                         </div>

                                            <div id="filterpop">
                                                 <div class='tb-dropdown tb-fieldfilter-popup tb-fieldfilter-selectfieldfiltereditor-popup tb-fieldfilter-selectfieldfiltereditor-popup-large' style='display: block; min-width: 261px; z-index: 1001; opacity: 1; left: 513.609px; top: 195.75px;' data-turbodropdown-popup='' data-positioned='bottomleft'>
                                                    <div class='tb-fieldfilter-popup-fields'>
                                                        <select class='tb-select tb-fieldfilter-selectfieldfiltereditor-operators' data-turbofieldfilter-selectfieldfiltereditor-operator-field=''>
                                                         <option value='equals'>Equals</option>
                                                         <option value='notEquals'>Not Equals</option>
                                                         <option value='in'>In List</option>
                                                         <option value='notIn'>Not In List</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <span class='tb-fieldfilter-popup-errors' data-turbofieldfilter-selectfieldfiltereditor-operator-errors=''></span>
                                                        <span class='tb-fieldfilter-selectfieldfiltereditor-values' data-turbofieldfilter-selectfieldfiltereditor-value-fields=''>
                                                            <div class='tb-fieldfilter-selectfieldfiltereditor-selector tb-inlineselect tb-inlineselect-multiple' data-turbofieldfilter-selectfieldfiltereditor-selector=''>
                                                                <div class='tb-inlineselect-messages' data-turboinlineselect-messages=''>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class='tb-inlineselect-searchbox tb-text-field tb-text-field-with-feedback tb-searchbox' data-turboinlineselect-searchbox=''>
                                                                    <input type='text' class='tb-input' autocomplete='off' data-turbosearchbox-input='' placeholder='Search...'>
                                                                    <i class='tb-text-field-feedback' data-turbosearchbox-state-indicator=''></i>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class='tb-inlineselect-selected-items' data-turboinlineselect-selected-items=''>
                                                                    <div class='tb-inlineselect-selected-items-header' data-turboinlineselect-selected-items-header=''>
                                                                        <span class='tb-inlineselect-selected-items-title' data-turboinlineselect-selected-items-title=''>Selected:</span>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class='tb-inlineselect-selected-items-viewport' data-turboinlineselect-selected-items-viewport='' style='height: 150px;'>
                                                                        <div class='tb-inlineselect-selected-items-list' data-turboinlineselect-selected-items-list=''>
                                                                            <div data-turbolistview-item-key='0' class='tb-listview-item'>
                                                                                <div class='tb-inlineselect-item'>Unshipped</div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class='tb-inlineselect-search-results' data-turboinlineselect-search-results='' style=''>
                                                                    <div class='tb-inlineselect-search-results-header' data-turboinlineselect-search-results-header=''>
                                                                        <span class='tb-inlineselect-search-results-title' data-turboinlineselect-search-results-title=''>Search Results:</span>
                                                                        <span class='tb-inlineselect-select-all' data-turboinlineselect-select-all='' data-turboinlineselect-action='selectAll'>Select All</span>
                                                                        <span class='tb-inlineselect-unselect-all' data-turboinlineselect-unselect-all='' data-turboinlineselect-action='unselectAll'>Clear</span>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class='tb-inlineselect-search-results-viewport' data-turboinlineselect-search-results-viewport='' style='height: 150px;'>
                                                                        <div class='tb-inlineselect-search-results-list' data-turboinlineselect-search-results-list=''>
                                                                            <div data-turbolistview-item-key='0' class='tb-listview-item tb-inlineselect-selected-item'>
                                                                                <div class='tb-inlineselect-item'>Unshipped</div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div data-turbolistview-item-key='1' class='tb-listview-item'>
                                                                                <div class='tb-inlineselect-item'>Shipped</div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div data-turbolistview-item-key='2' class='tb-listview-item'>
                                                                                <div class='tb-inlineselect-item'>Partially Shipped</div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div data-turbolistview-item-key='4' class='tb-listview-item'>
                                                                                <div class='tb-inlineselect-item'>Pending Shipment</div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div data-turbolistview-item-key='8' class='tb-listview-item'>
                                                                                <div class='tb-inlineselect-item'>Canceled</div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div data-turbolistview-item-key='16' class='tb-listview-item'>
                                                                                <div class='tb-inlineselect-item'>Third Party Managed</div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div class='tb-inlineselect-search-results-truncated' data-turboinlineselect-search-results-truncated=''>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        <span class='tb-fieldfilter-popup-errors' data-turbofieldfilter-selectfieldfiltereditor-value-errors=''>
                                                        </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class='tb-fieldfilter-popup-buttons'>
                                                        <button class='tb-btn' data-turbofieldfilter-selectfieldfiltereditor-update=''>Update</button>
                                                        <a href='#' class='tb-btn-link' data-turbofieldfilter-selectfieldfiltereditor-cancel=''>Cancel</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                           </div>

                            </div>
                                </div>
    </div>
```

Controller file

```
public function index(request $request)
```

{

```
$productFilterType = $request->input('productFilterType');

return view('pages.order',array(
                   'productFilterType' =>$productFilterType,
            ));
```

}

jquery

```
      function productFilter(value) {
alert(value);
jQuery("#productFilterType").val(value);
jQuery("#tabForms").submit();
```

}

```
       $(document).on('click','#inputTagFilterId',function(){
      var label = $('#inputTagFilterId');
      var filterid = label.attr('class');
      alert(filterid);
      $("."+filterid).click(function(){
      $("#filterpop").show();
   });
  });
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes, of course, I have been trying but the problem is if I write my code here it will create a lot of confusion to try to solve this code. and I am asking for the way I will try to write the code on my own. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of answer/solution are you expecting here then? Without seeing any of your code all I can say is "Fix your errors, make it work"

Comment: ok, I am editing the question.

Comment: If you want a dropdown with multiple values, why not use `<select>` with `multiple`?

Comment: because I want to select one at a time and when the first one is selected then I select the second one but it should show both first filter and the second one both on the view page. and should be there even after I refresh the page it should close only after I click on close button.

Comment: you can take example of stackoverflow's tag selection part but the difference is this it opens the option after we write something and I have dropdown.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's happening there. Can't find a JS function called `productFilter ` and I miss a few bits and pieces, but I can say, that you fundamentally misunderstood the purpose, function and usage of views. Laravel is an MVC framework, which means you separate your business logic into a controller, HTML into a view and database logic into a model (which you have done). You should go back a bit and read how to use those pretty essential things: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/

Comment: yes, I know but because of my need, I used database and controller function in my view file. and you can check productFilter now sorry, it's my edited question so I missed